# Ajax is not working properly

Tags: php, ajax

Finding place when enter pincode using ajax php. But it doesn't work properly. When we enter each pincode that pincode is checked and then result of that place is displayed .

```
    <label for="pincode">Pin-Code:</label>
  <input name="pincode" type="text" class="text" id="pincode"  />
  <div id="section1"></div>
```

I am setting this section as input fields.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
         $('#pincode').keyup(function() {
                //ajax request
                $.ajax({
                     url: "pincode_check.php",
                    data: {
                        'pincode' : $('#pincode').val()
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) { console.log(data.success);
                        if(data.success){
                            $.each(data.results[0].address_components, function(index, val){
                                 console.log(index+"::"+val.long_name);                         
                                 $('#section1').append( val.long_name+'<br>');
                             });    
                        }       
                    },      
                });
            });
       });


    </script>
```

This is ajax section for send data to **pincode_check.php**.
I am doing  **pincode_check.php** look like below. Here passing value retrive in $pincode variable then using **maps.google.com** to find logitude of that place. Then find corresponding place. That place name display in below the form field. But it does not worked properly.

```
     <?php 
    $pincode=$_REQUEST['pincode'];
    $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$pincode.'&sensor=false');
    $response= json_decode($geocode); //Store values in variable
    $lat = $response->results[0]->geometry->location->lat; //Returns Latitude
    $long = $response->results[0]->geometry->location->lng; // Returns Longitude
    $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$lat.','.$long.'&sensor=false');
    $data= json_decode($geocode);

    if($data==true)
    { // Check if address is available or not
        $data->results[0]->formatted_address ;   
        $data->success=true;
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    else {
        $data->success= false;

        echo json_encode($data);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Use `on` instead of `live` if using `jQuery 1.7+`

Comment: And one more thing to change:-- replace `<div id="#section1"></div>` to `<div id="section1"></div>`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, In your ajax response `success` object was missed. I have rewritten the code,

also, **pincode_check.php**

```
if($data==true)
{ // Check if address is available or not
    $data->result[0]->formatted_address ;   
    $data->success=true;
    echo json_encode($data);
}
else {
    $data->success= false;      
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

In HTML: should be (**Remove `#` in html id element**)

```
<div id="section1"></div>
```

instead of

```
<div id="#section1"></div>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
         $('#pincode').keyup(function() {
                //ajax request
                $.ajax({
                     url: "pincode_check.php",
                    data: {
                        'pincode' : $('#pincode').val()
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) { console.log(data.success);
                        if(data.success){
                            $.each(data.results[0].address_components, function(index, val){
                                 console.log(index+"::"+val.long_name);                         
                                 $('#section1').append( val.long_name+'<br>');
                             });    
                        }       
                    },      
                });
            });
       });


    </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
  <label for="pincode">Pin-Code:</label>
  <input name="pincode" type="text" class="text" id="pincode"  />
  <div id="section1"></div>
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php 
    $pincode=$_REQUEST['pincode'];
    $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$pincode.'&sensor=false');
    $response= json_decode($geocode); //Store values in variable
    $lat = $response->results[0]->geometry->location->lat; //Returns Latitude
    $long = $response->results[0]->geometry->location->lng; // Returns Longitude
    $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$lat.','.$long.'&sensor=false');
    $data= json_decode($geocode);

    if($data==true)
    { // Check if address is available or not
        $data->result[0]->formatted_address ;   
        $data->success=true;
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    else {
        $data->success= false;

        echo json_encode($data);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Since he's using `live`, I think it will work outside of the ready handler.

Comment: i get  responds from location results but that result not display below the input feild

Comment: Right now i have displayed the long_name, you can replace the appropriate object. in your input filed just type `aa`, so i got some response for that letters

Comment: ok..but that value dispaly below our text feild but it not disalyed

Comment: Just to know that, whether you got the response below the text field or not?

Comment: Not.we canot dispaly result below the text feilds

Comment: so you mean, there is no response received!

Comment: @ Krish R respose recived.that dispaly in firebug tools consolve section.its result not depaly my index page

Comment: I have checked it append into page, Have used my full code. Make sure you have updated the `<div id="section1"></div>` instead of `<div id="#section1"></div>`

Comment: @ Krish R iam used above code and changed # in id section..but not see result in my page.

Comment: Thanks, Can you replace this `console.log(index+"::"+val.long_name);` with `alert(index+"::"+val.long_name);` and check whether you got the alert

Comment: @ Krish R not got any alert in my page

Comment: What you have typed in your textfield? just type `a` and wait for while.

Comment: @ Krish R ok.i type a then wait..but nothing happend

Comment: do you have a teamviewer setup? or `join.me` , can we have quick online  meeting if possible?

Comment: @ Krish R No  teamviewer setup ..how meet online

Comment: just install teamviewer , it is free softeware

Comment: @ Krish R ok.your partner id plse..install teamwear

Comment: Please share your  id!

Comment: Your teamviewer version higher than me! if possible can we use `join.me` and share the meeting ID.

Comment: ok.krish...result is got..in if condition result is changed to result then i got result..thank ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Debug your script.

Are you getting data in your $pincode variable?

```
var_dump($pincode);
```

I prefer use a defined method in the ajax request, like post:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "pincode_check.php",
    method: 'POST'
    data: {
        'pincode' : $('#pincode').val()
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.success ==true){
            $('#section1').html(data.address_components);
        }

    },

});
```

Your success function has already the response, there is no need to use the conditional:

```
if(data.success ==true){
            $('#section1').html(data.address_components);
        }
```

Try to debug it to know what data are you recieving:

```
success: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
        }

    },
```

Comment: In your php script debug the $data variable. You are using an incorrect conditional: if($data==true). $geocode do not contain true. file_get_contents returns the read data or FALSE on failure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this which has a ready handler

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#pincode').live('change', function() {
    //ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: "pincode_check.php",
        data: {
            'pincode' : $('#pincode').val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.success ==true){
                $('#section1').html(data.address_components);
            }

        },

    });
});




  });
</script>
```